# Redirect to another url when back button is clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a payment form in which user can enter all his card details,and when he clicks,he is taken to the banks 3D secure page. But,the problem is, the user can simply click on the back button of the browser and can go back to payment page, if he initiates a "pay now" again,there is a chance of multiple transaction and duplication of ref ids.

So my question is: is there some way I can redirect the user to a custom page when he clicks on back button which says "Session expired, so transaction has been cancelled." so that we avoid duplication of ref ids?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the below jquery for redirect your own url when clicking browser back button
andipedia.com

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          var hashLocation = location.hash;
          var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
          var hashName = hashSplit[1];

          if (hashName !== '') {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            if (hash === '') {
              alert('Back button was pressed.');
                window.location='www.example.com';
                return false;
            }
          }
        });

        window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
      }

    });
```

Comment: Its working.. when i click browser back button its going to home page.  i have added this code to some x page  when i went to x page from anywhere /#forward is added to url that time am getting x page

Answer (score 1):

> If user clicked back button this will redirect you to your specified
>   page (100% Working)

```
window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "");

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event){
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
        // Code to handle back button or prevent from navigation
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi dont we need to specify the function name?will it happen immediately after the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use history api, and for better compatibility use [history.js plugin](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/).

Handling pressing back button :

```
$(window).bind('onpopstate', function(e){
   //your dark doings here
});
```

Comment: so will i be able to use a url inside this to get redirected

Answer (score 0):

You can use Brooke's modified script. That's a long script (should be used as external file). You can download it [here](http://bappi-d-great.com/redirect-to-another-page-when-back-button-is-pressed-in-javascript/)!

Then use the script like this:

```
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function(){
    document.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```