# How to redirect in index not Login form when I press Back in navigation

Tags: php, html

Hello guys After I login It redirect in a certain page but when I press back in browser I want to redirect it into my certain page not login page again. Thank you for helping me guys this problem takes me 4hrs and continuing Thank you!!!

**index.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="margin-top">
        <div class="row">   
        <div class="span12">



            <div class="login">
            <div class="log_txt">
            <p><strong>Please Enter the Details Below..</strong></p>
            </div>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                <button id="login" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-signin icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            $username = $_POST['username'];
                            $password = $_POST['password'];


                            $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysqli_error());
                            $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                                if( $num_row > 0 ) {
                                    ?>  
header('location:attendance.php');

                            $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];

                                }

                                else{ ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">Access Denied</div>     
                            <?php
                            }}
                            ?>
                    </form>

            </div>
        </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771045/redirect-to-another-url-when-back-button-is-clicked-using-javascript

Comment: @Batman thanks Ill read that

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to check to see if the user is logged in right at the top of your script and redirect them at that point instead of rendering you page.

And look into escaping your inputs against SQL injection before you put this where people can get to it.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header('Location: attendance.php');
}
?>
```

At the head of your file should do it.

Comment: can you give me an example referring to my code? thanks

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you!! well you said SQL injection i don't know how can i convert my codes to prevent sql injection btw thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the session, if session is valid u can return the user to Homepage else return to Login page.