# Redirect or refresh on browser back button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've search solutions for my issue and although I'm close to what I want to achieve, I still don't have a consistent result.

Here's my issue : I want the browser to actually do a redirect in a specific page when the user's clicks on the browser's back button or do an actual refresh of the page it is navigating back to in the history. Using the browser cached version of that page is leading to errors as some data are not refreshing properly.

This is what I got for the moment (based notably on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20771309) :

```
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
            window.location.href= "/page/I/want/to/force/a/refresh/of";
            return false;
        });

        window.history.pushState('', null);
    }
```

This works most of the time...but not always. Sometimes it just won't do it and I've yet to understand why exactly.

To be honest, as the stackloverflow solution above does not provide an explanation, I'm certainly not understanding exactly what it does. I've read about the History API as well as 'popstate' but I don't understand why we need to execute the "pushtate" method before leaving the condition (I've left the parameters empty as they don't seem to be relevant in my case) as well as why the 'popstate' event function has to return something.

I'm sure that my lack of understanding explains why my code does not work all the time.

Could you enlighten me a bit ? Feel free to suggest another option if this is not the proper way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Thank you !

Comment: Just a side note, but if you're doing something hacky like this then it's a clear indication of a bigger issue with the application.  Instead of forcing a page refresh/redirect when the user clicks back, figure out why using a cached version of the page causes problems and correct it.  Then the back button can work in its intended way.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing indeed, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hi, why did you deleted this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74207397/8816585