# Solution to generate API documentation based on static content (Javascript/VueJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, documentation, asciidoctor

I'm working on a Vue 2 project where one of the goals would be to be able to generate a standard API documentation front-end based on static content. The syntax of the content is yet to be defined (markdown, adoc, etc.) but the current idea is to have the documentation integrated in an existing Vue/Nuxt solution.

To be clear, I'm not talking of something "limited" to endpoints description in the vein of swaggerUI but a full documentation layout : dynamic navigation drawer, content structure support (chapters, subchapters, etc), handling of code blocks, images, etc. [See Stripe API for reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api).

I'm doing researches and I've been exploring solutions like VuePress, AsciiDoctorJs, or Docsify etc. but the more I search, the more solutions I encounter and it's not always easy to really grasp what can they cover and how well they will behave in a Vue environment. A lot of them are just basically their own framework and I'm not too sure how well it would integrate with Nuxt for instance.
I also need to find something robust with a decent community behind it.

Of course, I don't expect to find the solution that will process any md file for me with 0 custom code to write, I fully expect headaches for any solution I end up choosing; I sense the solution will also probably be a mix of several products. But I'd love your input on the topic as you might suggest solutions I haven't found yet or another approach to the project.

Thanks !

Comment: So I'm not sure what is the main issue here: use Vitepress. It's done for that specific purpose and works well.

Comment: Unfortunately @kissu, I'm stuck with Vue 2 at the moment (the project relies on Vuetify which is stuck on Vue 2)and VitePress is a Vue 3 solution.

Comment: Why do you need it to support Vuetify? It's a documentation tool, not your actual app.

Comment: @kissu I don't need it for the documentation tool itself but the project these documentations will be available in is using Vuetify.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question fully, but https://antora.org/ might be interesting.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Antora looks very similar to what I try to achieve. But from the researches I did, all these solutions always end up being based on local files, either static one, or generated like for Antora. There doesn't seem to exist a solution to retrieve an markdown file/ascii doc content from an API and process it as a documentation file, with support for navigation, etc. Render such a remote file in Vue is easy but generate a documentation out of it seems more complex. I'll probably have to create my custom solution. Thanks.

Comment: Vuetify is available as a [stable 3.0 version](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v3.0.0) for almost a month. You can probably integrate it into Vitepress now.